# Cosmos DB ODBC driver installation problem

Tags: errors, odbc, windows-server, cosmos-db

We are trying to install Cosmos DB ODBC Driver following the instructions provided [in this Microsoft Azure resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/odbc-driver) and are running into the following error:

> The setup routines for Microsoft DocumentDB ODBC Driver ODBC driver could not be loaded due to a system error code 126: The specified module could not be found. (C:\Program Files\Microsoft DocumentDB ODBC Driver\lib\DocumentDBODBC_sb64.dll).

We've tried unsuccessfully on Windows Server 2008R2 and Windows Server 2012R2.  We have it working on several Windows 10 desktops, just not server OS's unfortunately.  We tried several things like installing using run as administrator, from command line, with both 32 and 64 bit installed, and then one or the other.  We opened the location of the DLL to 'Everyone/full control' We checked that the Visual C++ redistributables are installed although not sure which specific ones are needed.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2012, 2013 and 2015. We had the exact same issue with Cosmos ODBC Drivers and this resolved it in Windows 2012 R2 server.